# Cannot upload image on site

Tags: 8, media, files

In content type I added an image field.

Now when I try to add a content and upload an image, I am getting this error on page.

```
The file could not be saved. An unknown error has occurred.
File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.
```

**CONFIG:**

File system setting.

**Public file base URL:**

> http://drupal.com/sites/default/files

**Temporary directory:**

> sites/default/files/temp

*Reading note about the Temporary directory:*

> A local file system path where temporary files will be stored. This
>   directory should not be accessible over the web.

Since its path is located inside Drupal, I am assuming that this causes the error.

**Checking the system logs:**

> "POST
>   /node/add/finfeed1?element_parents=field_image/widget/0&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 6434

PS: I have 777 on sites/default/files/temp

Comment: Check the disk size on your web server as a first clue.

Comment: It has allocated 1GiB size.

Comment: I have struggled with something similar, and for me it was a Selinux problem. What server are you running on?

Comment: I once was using Mac. I manage to reinstall the site and the error gone. now I'm using Linux.